# Transfer map between simplicial manifolds

Tags: simplicial-stuff, manifolds, simplicial-complexes

Let $M^m$ and $N^n$ be two triangulated oriented and closed manifolds and $f:M\to N$ a simplicial map. For each $a\in H_p(N)$ we may consider its homological transfer $f_!a\in H_{m-n+p}(M)$.

I want to use the simplicial structure to describe this transferred class explicitely. Let $c\in C_p(N)$ be a cycle representing $a$ in the simplicial chain. Is there any possibility to construct an explicit cycle $c'\in C_{m-n+p}(M)$ representing $f_!a$?

Intuitively (inspired from the standard exercise “transfer for coverings”) for each simplex $\sigma\in C_p(N)$ I would take all $(m-n+p)$-simplicies of $M$ lying in the preimage $f^{-1}(\sigma)$ into account. However, in order to sum them up, the simplices have to get signs (which, in some way, should correspond the the signs in the fundamental cycle …).